# Get Path Of Existing Directory or File, Paste at Cursor Position

Tags: linux, vim

I am using `vim` to edit config files on newly-built linux servers.  On these boxes I have a default `vim` setup (RHEL 6.2).

While editing these files, I'd like to avoid fat-fingering directory & file paths whenever possible.

Suppose I have a file `foo.conf` opened in the editor, the contents of which I've just entered:

> myfoo=

The cursor is currently to the right of the `=` in this file.  I'd like to use vim to insert the name of a directory here.  Suppose it's a directory that exists: `/etc/foo`, and that I'm lazy and so would like to use as few keystrokes as possible.

Can get vim to do this?

I cannot add any plugins to vim, nor can I change its configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the output from `ls` and format like this:

1. <kbd>ESC</kbd>
2. `:r!ls -d /etc/f`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. <move one line up, e.g. <kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>⇧</kbd>>
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
5. <kbd>X</kbd>

Explanation:

1. Goes to "command" mode (technically "normal" mode).
2. `:r` reads input from a source and inserts it after the current line, `!` interprets the following as a shell command and executes it.
3. Go up.
4. `J` joins a line with the next, and also inserts a space in between.
5. Remove the extra inserted space.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Shift+x`? That is not standard, is it? It doesn't work here. I'd do `:r!echo /etc/f <tab completion> <Enter> kJx`

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed the answer there was a typo in the `<kbd>` syntax

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense :-) . It is exactly the same as my version then, except the `echo` trick which is completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Use omnicompletion: hit `<C-x><C-f>`, choose, `<CR>`, repeat…

Comment: Cool, though this appears to work only for files in the current dir?  I need to look into this.  There's a [vim tip page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion) on this as well.

Comment: No. After `/` it will list the first level of directories of your filesystem. After `../` it will list all the directories contained in the directory above.